# Problem in writing openMp code, it doesn't work as expected

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I was asked to i was asked to write an OpenMP programs that calculates the Euclidean distance between two vectors of equal length n. Each process/thread should generate a portion of each vector and compute the local sum of the element-wise squares of their differences. Finally, all processes/threads should send their local sums to process/thread 0, which should sum them, take the square root of the result, and print it.

so I wrote these two code:

**1- sequential code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

   double res=0;
   double d;
   int n=350000;
   int a[n];
   int b[n];
   clock_t start,end;
   
   for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
      a[i]=i+1;
      b[i]=i+3;
   }
   start = clock();
   
   for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
      d = pow((a[i] - b[i]), 2);
      res = res + d;
   }   
   res = sqrt(res);
   end = clock();
  
   
   printf("The result is: %f\nwork took: %f seconds\n",res,((double)(end-start))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

   return 0;
}
```

**2- OpenMP code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int n = 10000000;
    double start, end;
    double *a = (double *) malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double *b = (double *) malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double local_sum = 0, threads_sum = 0;

    // Initialize vectors a and b
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
        b[i] = i * 2;
    }



    start = omp_get_wtime(); 
    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    omp_set_num_threads(16);

    // Calculate local sum 
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:local_sum)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        double diff = a[i] - b[i];
        local_sum += diff * diff;
    }

    // Calculate threads sum  
   #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:threads_sum)
   for (int i = 0; i < omp_get_num_threads(); i++) {
        threads_sum += local_sum;
    }

    // Calculate Euclidean distance
   
    double euclidean_distance = sqrt(threads_sum);
    end = omp_get_wtime();

    printf("Euclidean distance between vectors a and b: %f\nTime taken: %f\n", euclidean_distance, end - start);

    free(a);
    free(b);

    return 0;
}
```

but I got this feedback: "Your sequential code is fine. However, your OpenMP code is wrong as it does not do the required task. You could write a correct OpenMP code by simply adding an OpenMP statement above the for loop in your sequential code. This would enable parallel execution of the loop iterations."

based on the feedback, does this simple code is good?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
    int n = 350000;
    double start, end;
    double res = 0;
    double d;
    int *a = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    int *b = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = i + 1;
        b[i] = i + 3;
    }

    start = omp_get_wtime();

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:res)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        d = pow((a[i] - b[i]), 2);
        res += d;
    }

    res = sqrt(res);
    end = omp_get_wtime();

    printf("The result is: %f\nWork took: %f seconds\n", res, end - start);

    free(a);
    free(b);

    return 0;
}
```

or the problem is that i have to add these two line before the loops? I add "schedule(static)"

`#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) reduction(+:local_sum)`

`#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) reduction(+:threads_sum)`

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Your last code example with just `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:res)` is the right one. But you could check which codes are ok or not just by testing if the result is the same as the sequential version.